# "About me" page, text and photo side by side in one box with borders

Tags: html, css

I want to make a "About me" page that would contain a box with a thin border, pin to the center of the page.

I need some text on the left half of the box and an image on the right side of the box.

I have a hard time doing that with `<div>` and it just doesn't work the way I want it.
How do I solve this problem.

**Below you can see my code so far:**

```
<div style="background-color: white;
     border: 5px solid #3D65A9;
     padding: 50px;
     margin: 20px;">

     <h4 style="text-align: left; 
                font-family:'Cinzel'; 
                white-space:pre-line; 
                margin-left: 10px;
                display: inline-block">Hi everyone!!Random text.
     </h4>
     <img src="Moja-slika.jpg" alt="Moja slika" style="width:30%">
</div>
```

This is what I get, and I want my text to be on top, not on the bottom.
And I want to make image and whole  smaller. 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `vertical-align` property?

Comment: Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, mark the actual answer as solved, dont edit the title of your question to solved.

Comment: Hi @MisterOggy, although it is not in your question, I advise you to put the styles in classes, not inline. It will help you organize your code and make future changes easier and faster. I put an answer with this.

Comment: Hi, yeah, I know about that but I'm trying to avoid using classes and functions because I don't know how to properly use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `float:left;` the image, if it's a child of the `<h4></h4>` element, like so:

```
<div style="background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid #3D65A9;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;">
<h4 style="text-align: left; font-family:'Cinzel'; white-space:pre-line; margine-left: 10px;display: inline-block">
  <img src="Moja-slika.jpg" alt="Moja slika" style="width:30%; float:left;"> Hi everyone!!
Random text.</h4>

</div>
```

However, it would be good practise to clear the float, see this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_float.asp) for more information.

Comment: This worked. Now, How do I make a small space between photo and text, because it is too close?

Comment: And yes, I tried using float but it didn't work before.

Comment: Yah, it depends where you apply the float, have a look through the article i linked it explains it a bit. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `vertical-align`

```html
<div style="background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid #3D65A9;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;">
  <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-itYtAL5lBeE/TkFdlIhhacI/AAAAAAAABHI/HYGHzdl85UI/s1600/111433_aerogenerador.jpg" alt="Moja slika" style="width:30%">
<h4 style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-family:'Cinzel'; white-space:pre-line; margine-left: 10px;display: inline-block">Hi everyone!!
Random text.</h4>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="background-color: white; border: 5px solid #3D65A9; padding: 50px; 
  margin: 20px;">
     <h4 style="text-align: left; font-family:'Cinzel'; white-space:pre-line; 
      margine-left: 10px;display: inline-block; float:right">
        Hi everyone!! Random text.
     </h4>
   <img src="Moja-slika.jpg" alt="Moja slika" style="float:left" width="100" height="100">
 </div>
```

This should get the paragraph to be at the top.  You could then use margins to center it. To make the image smaller, add the height and width properties and set the values to the size you want.

Comment: It doesn't work as I would like to. But thanks. I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use position absolute in your h4 tag:

```
     <div
      style="background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid #3D65A9;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;position: relative;"
    >
    <img src="img/amorgos.webp" alt="Moja slika" style="width:30%" />

      <h4
        style="text-align: left; font-family:'Cinzel'; white-space:pre-line;display: inline-block;position: absolute;
        top: 29px;
        margin: 0;"
      >
        Hi everyone!! Random text.
      </h4>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not working the right way, but thank you. I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet you can see an example of the layout you want.

- The img should have a div that wraps it.
- Do not put inline styles. Instead, use classes.
- I recommend you this interesting web about [layout](http://learnlayout.com/)
- Next, it is very useful to learn [flexbox](https://cssreference.io/flexbox/)

```css
.about__wrapper {
 background-color: white;
 border: 5px solid #3D65A9;
 width: 400px;
 height: 150px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-around;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 padding: 10px;
}

.about__image--wrapper {
 width: 25%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.about__image {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.about__text {
 width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="about__wrapper">
 <div class="about__image--wrapper">
  <img
   class="about__image"
   src="https://place-hold.it/100x100.jpg"
   alt="image-name" />
 </div>
 <div class="about__text">
  Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text Random text 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it looks great. Thanks.